# Cannot register device in Azure NotificationHub on iOS, no callbacks

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to set up push notifications via Azure NotificationHub (using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#configure-ios-for-notifications) [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/ios-sdk-get-started#configure-the-notification-hub-with-apns-information)). Android went fine, but iOS...

No matter what I do, I do not receive any callbacks from **RegisterNative** / **RegisterTemplate** methods of **SBNotificationHub**, and no registrations appear in the hub.

My code (pretty straightforward):

```
public static void SubscribeToAzure(NSData deviceToken, string[] subscriptionTags = null, bool bUnsubscribe = false)
{
    try
    {
        var Hub = new SBNotificationHub(AppConstants.ListenConnectionString, AppConstants.NotificationHubName);

        Logger.WriteLine($"Unsubscribing from AzureHub [{deviceToken}]....");

        Hub.UnregisterAll(deviceToken, (error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine($"SubscribeToAzure: Unable to call unregister, {error}");
                return;
            }
            RuntimeInfo.AzureSubscribed = false;

            if (bUnsubscribe)
                return;

            Logger.WriteLine($"Register native in AzureHub [{deviceToken}]....");

            var tags = subscriptionTags != null ? new NSSet(subscriptionTags.ToArray()) : new NSSet("default");
            Hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, tags, errorCallback =>
            {
                // !!! never got here !!!

                if (errorCallback != null)
                    Logger.WriteLine($"RegisterNative error: {errorCallback}");
                else
                    Logger.WriteLine($"RegisterNative OK");
            });

            Logger.WriteLine("Register template in AzureHub....");

            var templateExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

            Hub.RegisterTemplate(deviceToken, "defaultTemplate", AppConstants.APNTemplateBody, templateExpiration, tags, errorCallback =>
            {
                // !!! never got here !!!

                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    Logger.WriteLine($"RegisterTemplateAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.WriteLine("Subscribed to Azure successfully.");
                    RuntimeInfo.AzureSubscribed = true;
                }
            });

            Logger.WriteLine("Registrations passed....");
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.WriteLine($"SubscribeToAzure: Whole deal failed, {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

Always get this log messages (no callbacks called):

> [22.10.2020 18:13:43]: Unsubscribing from AzureHub [{length = 32, bytes = 0x342c9bc5 d75ffb0b d68078d0 47e94320 ... e08989c9 66a13a37}]....

> [22.10.2020 18:13:44]: Register native in AzureHub [{length = 32, bytes = 0x342c9bc5 d75ffb0b d68078d0 47e94320 ... e08989c9 66a13a37 }]....

> [22.10.2020 18:13:44]: Register template in AzureHub....

> [22.10.2020 18:13:44]: Registrations passed....

And no iOS registrations in the hub. And no errors anywhere.

I tried both certificate and token authentication modes, with no luck.

I have double-, triple- and quadruple-checked all certificates, statuses, keys, ids, etc.

Using iOS SDK 14.0, iPhone X iOS 14.0.1, Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1560, Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS 3.1.0.

=======

I was advised to move from **SBNotificationHub** to **[MSNotificationHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin#getting-started-with-xamarin-for-apple)**.

Got exactly the same result: no response if something went wrong or not. And no registrations in the hub.

```
public static void SubscribeToAzure(NSData deviceToken, string[] subscriptionTags = null, bool bUnsubscribe = false)
{
    RuntimeInfo.AzureSubscribed = false;

    if (bUnsubscribe)
    {
        // ??
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {

            Logger.WriteLine("Subscribing to Azure Hub....");

            MSNotificationHub.Start(AppConstants.ListenConnectionString, AppConstants.NotificationHubName);

            MSNotificationHub.SetDelegate(new NotificationDelegate());

            MSNotificationHub.SetLifecycleDelegate(new InstallationLifecycleDelegate());

            MSNotificationHub.ClearTags();

            if (subscriptionTags != null)
                foreach (string tag in subscriptionTags)
                {
                    MSNotificationHub.AddTag(tag);
                }

            var template = new MSInstallationTemplate();
            template.Body = AppConstants.APNTemplateBody;

            if (subscriptionTags != null)
                foreach (string tag in subscriptionTags)
                {
                    template.AddTag(tag);
                }

            MSNotificationHub.SetTemplate(template, key: "defaultTemplate");


            Logger.WriteLine($"SubscribeToAzure: done subscribing routine");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.WriteLine($"SubscribeToAzure: Whole deal failed, {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
public class InstallationLifecycleDelegate : MSInstallationLifecycleDelegate
{
    public override void DidFailToSaveInstallation(MSNotificationHub notificationHub, MSInstallation installation, NSError error)
    {
        Logger.WriteLine($"Subscribing to Azure failed with exception: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
    }

    public override void DidSaveInstallation(MSNotificationHub notificationHub, MSInstallation installation)
    {
        RuntimeInfo.AzureSubscribed = true;
        Logger.WriteLine($"Subscribed to Azure successfully with Installation ID: {installation.InstallationId}");
    }
}
public class NotificationDelegate : MSNotificationHubDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceivePushNotification(MSNotificationHub notificationHub, MSNotificationHubMessage message)
    {
        NSDictionary userInfo = message.UserInfo;
        if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Background)
        {
            Logger.WriteLine($"Message received in the background with title {message.Title} and body {message.Body}");
            ProcessNotification(userInfo, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.WriteLine($"Message received in the foreground with title {message.Title} and body {message.Body}");
            ProcessNotification(userInfo, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Log only shows that all parts of code were passed:

> [23.10.2020 18:34:33]: Subscribing to Azure Hub....

> [23.10.2020 18:34:33]: SubscribeToAzure: done subscribing routine

Also tried automatic [swizzle disabling](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin#disabling-automatic-swizzling) to log every step, same result.

---

### UPDATE

After few days of struggling, I found out that if execution slips from main thread, iOS blocks requests and Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS wouldn't say anything about it. Running it forcibly in main thread gave it a nudge.
Sadly, it still doesn't work.

The first approach with *SBNotificationHub* failed to register template. Code above do **RegisterNative** and I get native entry in notification hub. But **RegisterTemplate** return 'Bad Request'.

> [28.10.2020 15:26:10]: RegisterTemplateAsync error: URLRequest failed for <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x282bac6e0> { URL: https://webtutormobile.servicebus.windows.net//Registrations/8635975298502840400-8846379580641729326-3?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: bad request

Second approach with *MSNotificatoinHub* fail to obtain NSDictionary from MSNotificationHubMessage.UserInfo getter, and breaks on this line:

```
public override void DidReceivePushNotification(MSNotificationHub notificationHub, MSNotificationHubMessage message)
{
        var userInfo = message.UserInfo; // MSNotificationHubMessage.UserInfo has type NSDictionary<NSString, NSString>
```

with exception:

> [28.10.2020 16:22:58]: Received azure notification error: Unable to cast object of type 'Foundation.NSDictionary' to type 'Foundation.NSDictionary`2[[Foundation.NSString, Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065],[Foundation.NSString, Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]]'

Comment: Are you testing in a real device?

Comment: Of course. As I mentioned before, it's iPhone X iOS 14.0.1

Comment: It's hard to say what's the problem without any error log. I would recommend you to follow the document step by step and write the code again. Also, you can open an issue in github for more help.

Comment: Lack of errors or any "feedback" is the main reason I got stuck.

Comment: Can you please check again the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started) in the document and here is also a [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/Azure/NotificationHubs) you can refer.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, in this days I double-checked everything numerouse times, even tried to create everything from scratch. Also, you sample project is pretty strange (for example, method RegisterNativeAsync doesn't have callback parameter, only RegisterNative has). Anyway, I have managed to advance a little further and have added update to the topic. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you please override the FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications method to get some information about failure?

Comment: FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications never called because it's successfully register in APNS, it cannot register Template in Azure Hub with "hub.RegisterTemplate" method. (400) Bad request. Native registration in Azure Hub is OK.

Comment: Have you tried to open an issue in github to get more help? It's really hard to find out the cause without any error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it has been brought to conclusion. If anyone's interested:

1. Hub Registrations must be called in main thread. Otherwise *Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS* wouldn't even give a hint that something went wrong.
2. New approach with *MSNotificationHub* has a bug in getting UserInfo with casting it to NSDictionary<NSString, NSString> when actual type is NSDictionary. It is issued in GitHub for a while now, but still without any response from team, so if you pass any data besides message through push notification, sorry, it's no go.
3. Old approach using *SBNotificationHub* has strict Template format. First of all, you shoud use *RegisterTemplate* method that outs error, not one that do callback, as the former one is the only that gives error description for some reason.
   Secondly, you can't define template using *{$(field)}* constructon, you need to specify insertion format for properties, like: *"alert":"$(messageParam)","badge":"#(badge)","content-available":"#(contentAvailable)"* etc. Also you need to modify dispatcher so it would always send unquoted parameters.

IOS implementation is extremely raw, half-done and forgotten. I understand that interacting with Apple is utter hell and pain in the rear, but still...

Hope it saves someone lots and lots of time.

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Serg's answer, you need to use the `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` for `MSNotificationHub` registration.

Don't use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my answer. I have working azure pushes now, but my solution mixes the new and the old approaches. Each of them does not work separately.

**For android:**
When I use the new approach there is registration at the azure notification hub, but notifications doesn't receive.
When I use the old approach there is no notifications from the azure notification hub.

1. Hub registrations must be called in`RunOnUiThread` for the new approach:

```
    NotificationHub.Start(MainActivity.Instance.Application, NotificationHubName, ConnectionString);
    NotificationHub.SetListener(new AzureListener());
```

2. Implementations of the `AzureListener` class is the stub:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// It does nothing, but registrasion doesn't work without it.
    /// </summary>
    public class AzureListener : Java.Lang.Object, INotificationListener
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Stub
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
        {}
    }
```

3. Hub registrations must be called in the non main thread for the old approach:

```
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        this.notificationHub = new WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub(NotificationHubName,ConnectionString, MainActivity);
        
        notificationHub.UnregisterAll(PnsHandle);
        notificationHub.Register(PnsHandle, new string[] { });
    }
```

4. It's need to implement the `FirebaseMessagingService` class for receiving pushes.

**For iOS:**
When I use the new approach there is no registration at the azure notification hub.
When I use the old approach there is registration at the azure hub, but there is no notifications from the azure notification hub.

1. Hub registrations must be called in the `MainThread` for the new approach:

```
    MSNotificationHub.Start(ConnectionString, NotificationHubName);
    MSNotificationHub.SetDelegate(new AzureNotificationHubListener());
```

2. Hub registrations must be called in the xamarin main thread for the old approach:

```
    await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
    {
        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(connectionParameters.ConnectionString, connectionParameters.NotificationHubName);
        await Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(AppDelegate.PnsHandle, null);
    });
```

3. It's need to implement `AzureNotificationHubListener` class for receiving pushes.
4. It's need to add key to the `Info.plist`:

   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
   </dict>