# Xamarin.Forms iOS app doesn't register with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I created a Xamarin.forms app and want to implement push notification functionality in iOS through Azure Notification Hub. To achieve this, I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started) from Microsoft

However, when I try to send a test message through Azure Notification Hub, I always get the following message back: "Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets".

I'm using the following code to register with Azure Notification Hub:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

    Hub.UnregisterAll (deviceToken, (error) => {
    if (error != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
        return;
    }

    Hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
        if (errorCallback != null)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterNative error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
    });
});
}
```

No errors are returned/logged.

RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is always automatically invoked when the app is started, but whenever I try to read the information from NSData deviceToken, it's always null. I tried to read the content of the deviceToken through various ways:

```
byte[] result = new byte[deviceToken.Length];         
Marshal.Copy(deviceToken.Bytes, result, 0, (int)deviceToken.Length);
var token = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", ""); // returns null
```

In my FinishedLaunching method I have:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                (granted, error) => InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications));
    }
    else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
    {
        var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                new NSSet());

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
    }
    else
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I searched about this, but there's little information about such issues. Also, all permissions for notifications have been set.

I'm using Xamarin Hot Restart to debug on an iOS device. I'm aware that Xamarin Hot Restart has some limitations, but I don't see anything about push notifications in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart).

Comment: Are you testing on a real device? And you can check the points in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513220/cannot-register-device-in-azure-notificationhub-on-ios-no-callbacks?noredirect=1#comment114206139_64513220) to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested on a real device and I followed all the points in that answer, but it didn't help. I'm wondering if this is just a limitation of using Xamarin Hot Restart, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: No, xamarin hot restart won't affect the notification. Can you please have a try with the suggestions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/77789/view.html)?

Comment: I tried the solutions from your link, but it didn't help unfortunately. I also checked Visual Studio 2019 Server Explorer, but the iOS app doesn't show itself in the registrations list. I did [read](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios) that SBNotificationHub is obsolete now, but it also says it's still supported. Microsoft's tutorial also uses SBNotificationHub.

Comment: It's hard to point out the error and your codes looks well so far. Can you please follow the document and check all the points again. Like certifications, tokens and etc.